# How to parse information not using explode?

Tags: php, parsing, explode, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have some Information which i have parsed from the Wikipedia Infobox using the Wikipedia API. One of my Information which i want to parse is the birthdate:

`$birthdate = "birth_date = {{Birth date|1958|8|29}}"`

i want have the birtdate information that the output is like this:

`1958-8-29`

in my considerations i can use the php function `explode` but i think this is a very bad way to get in each case the right information back.

My Question is:

Does anyone know a way to parse the birthdate information in each case right, independently from the other content?
And if yes, can you make a example?

Comment: regular expressions.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php

Comment: You might want to consider using WikiData instead: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P569

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one with regular expression.

```
$matches = array();
$birthdate = "birth_date = {{Birth date|1958|8|29}}";
preg_match('/^(.*)\|([0-9]{4})\|([0-9]{1,2})\|([0-9]{1,2})}}/is', $birthdate, $matches);
if (!empty($matches[2]) && !empty($matches[3]) && !empty($matches[4])) {
    echo $matches[2]."-".$matches[3]."-".$matches[4];
} else {
    echo 'Not found the parts of the date';
}
//Output is: 1958-8-29
```